# swift 3 posting json parameter to api

Tags: json, swift3

I need to pass the following json to this function so Shopify Api can understand the submission.

Every time I execute this code, I get an error message that there is a missing required parameter. Obviously, I am unable to create the correct variable format and pass it to server.

Shopify API is expecting the following json to be passed via POST

```
{
    "customer": {
        "first_name": "Steve",
        "last_name": "Lastnameson",
        "email": "steve.lastnameson@example.com",
        "verified_email": true,
        "addresses": [
            {
                "address1": "123 Oak St",
                "city": "Ottawa",
                "province": "ON",
                "phone": "555-1212",
                "zip": "123 ABC",
                "last_name": "Lastnameson",
                "first_name": "Mother",
                "country": "CA"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my posting code:

```
let customer = [
    "customer": [
        "first_name": "Steve",
        "last_name": "Lastnameson",
        "email": "steve.lastnameson@example.com",
        "verified_email": "true",
        "addresses": [
            [
                "address1": "123 Oak St",
                "city": "Ottawa",
                "province": "ON",
                "phone": "555-1212",
                "zip": "123 ABC",
                "last_name": "Lastnameson",
                "first_name": "Mother",
                "country": "CA",
            ],
        ],
    ],
] as [String: Any]

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: shopUrl + "/admin/customers.json")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: customer, options: [])

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    } else {
        do {
            guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] else { return }

            guard let errors = json?["errors"] as? [[String: Any]] else { return }
                if errors.count > 0 {
                    // show error
                    return
                } else {
                    // show confirmation
                }
            }
        }
    }).resume()
```

Comment: What is the exact response that you are getting from the server?

Comment: to create a new customer account

Comment: the problem is that the server is not getting the data in the expected format

Comment: Yes I read your question, but what is the expected format that the server is telling you in the response?

Comment: it is expecting the json I put at the top

Comment: here is the api reference: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/customer#create

Comment: Ok, let's rephrase that. What is the data (response) that the server is giving back to you after you send the request?

Comment: Optional(["errors": {
    customer = "Required parameter missing or invalid";
}])

Comment: Verified email should be a boolean and not a string

Comment: yeah, I tried that. Still the same result

Comment: does "steve.lastnameson@example.com" already have an account from a previous test?

Comment: getting same issue.. @Hamid did you find any solution for shopify?

Answer (score 5):

The request needs to have the content type declared. Add:

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```